# Web Application creation using VS2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, vs-web-application-project, .net-framework-version

I am tryin to write a GUI code for A window form application using VS 2010 (.netframework 4.0). However when inculde UI as in :

```
using System.Web.UI; 
using System.Web.SessionState;
```

it tells me

```
the type or namespace name 'UI' does not exist in the namespace System.Web
```

and same prob for sessionstate.

What should i do?

Comment: You don't want `Web.UI`.. you aren't creating a web app..

Comment: Are you trying to create a web app or a windows form app?  Your subject says one thing, your message body the other.

Answer (score 1):

To create a windows form app you want the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace to build your UI.

Take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/net-web-services-5-steps-2/) for how to consume a web service; assuming you're not creating the service too you should start at step 2 (halfway down the page I linked to).

Comment: I am tryin to develop a Windows Form application that consumes a service.. in the application i need to use the GUI.

Comment: You're confused. System.Web.UI is for web forms applications, not windows forms applications. Which class do you want to use from that namespace? To consume a web service, use "Add Service Reference"

Comment: @JohnSaunders  oops, fixed.